# After state restoration, dismissViewControllerAnimated is not using the same animation

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, state-restoration

I'm implementing an iOS app using storyboards where a button calls `dismissViewControllerAnimated` to move back from a view controller `B` to the previous view controller `A`.

Between the two controllers, I've set a modal segue using an horizontal flip animation:

> `View Controller A → (Modal Segue with Flip transition) → View Controller B`

Tapping the button, the `dismissViewControllerAnimated` executes the Flip transition *reversed*, as expected.

But when the app is using the state restoration mechanism to display the controller `B`, the transition used is the standard one (the view is popped out) instead the Flip transition.

How can I make  `dismissViewControllerAnimated` use the same transition type also after restoration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `modalTransitionStyle` to `UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal` after the restoration is complete.

Comment: Got it, thank you. I've set it in the app delegate 's`application:viewControllerWithRestorationIdentifierPath` method. When the last identifierComponents refers to the `B` controller, it set  `bViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .FlipHorizontal`.

Comment: @crumblenaut There is also `applicationFinishedRestoringState` that is called for each participating view controller which you can use.